# failing to create Active Record Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

This is an extremely simple Active Record association I am trying to create and it is frustrating that is is not being made successfully.

I have two models, post and user. 
User.rb has nothing but `has_many :posts`
and Post.rb has nothing but `belongs_to :user`.
I have run rake db:migrate and verified that there is a user_id column in my posts table.

When I go to the console, though, I am unable to make an association between new objects.

First, I make a new User instance like `max = User.create(:name=>"Max")`
Next, I make a new Post instance like `post = Post.create(:user_id=>1, title=>"FirstPost")`

I then try and type `max.posts` but get a `NoMethodError undefined method 'post='`
If I try and set up the association like `max.post = post`, I get the same error.

Lastly, I tried adding `attr_accessor :posts` to the User model.

Now, I can type `max.posts`, but I am just getting `nil`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: post de full error please

Comment: now that I added `attr_accessor :posts`, I'm not getting an error anymore, just `nil`

Comment: can you add the full code and the full error and logs of what you're doing? 'I did this and got this' doesn't really work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because there's no 'post=' method in User.

Try the following:

```
max = User.create(:name=> "Max")
max.posts.create(:title => "FirstPost")
max.posts
```

As an alternative way:

```
max = User.create(:name=> "Max")
post = Post.new(:user => max, :title => "FirstPost")
post.save
max.posts
```

Comment: Looking at the "alternative way" - so I would need to have a `user` column in my `posts` table, right? Why would that work but setting the `user_id` attribute not work?

Comment: you where specifying user_id "1" which may not be the id of the last created user.